# List of context-sensitive help parameters?

Tags: standard-objects, help

As documented here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=replacing_online_help.htm&language=en_US, it is possible to override the base URL to which the "Help for this Page" links for standard objects point. You can also parse the "target" and "section" parameters that will still be appended. Indeed, if you don't, it's likely a rather pointless exercise in sending your users to 404s, unless the target URL ignores or strips the parameters.

But does anyone know of or have a list of the values for those parameters?